# Existence of operator $B^2=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $A$ be hermitian operator on finite-dimensional inner-space $V$ whose eigenvalues are positive real numbers. Show that there exists hermitian operator $B$ such that $B^2=A$. Is $B$ unique?

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ is hermitian it can be diagonalized: $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ and $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues. By assumption, $\lambda_i>0$ so we can take their square root. Define
$$\sqrt{D}=\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},\ldots,\sqrt{\lambda_n})$$
and let
$$B=P\sqrt{D}P^{-1}.$$
This satisfies $B^2=A$ since
$$B^2=(P\sqrt{D}P^{-1})(P\sqrt{D}P^{-1})=P\sqrt{D}\sqrt{D}P^{-1}=PDP^{-1}=A.$$
It is not unique since, for example $-B$ has the same property.

Comment: if $B=P\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},\ldots,\sqrt{\lambda_n})P^{-1}.$ isn't $B^2=P^2\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},\ldots,\sqrt{\lambda_n})^2(P^{-2})$ which does not equal A

Comment: @RushThaMan Not quite. See the edit.

Comment: @RushThaMan The point is that for operators, $(AB)^2=ABAB\neq A^2B^2$.

Comment: Thanks man, you seem to be an expert. :D

Comment: Hey but we forgot one thing. We have to find operator B that s Hermitian. Is given B hermitian?

Comment: @RushThaMan Yes it is.

Comment: Why is it hermitian? The fact that it can be diagonalized in orthonormal basis isn't enough. I think at least.

Comment: @RushThaMan: In fact, it is enough since an operator on a finite dimensional complex vector space is Hermitian if and only if it is orthogonally diagonalizable with real eigenvalues.